# Oracle CURRENT_DATE doesn't work in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple query to filter out the `due_date` value is today.

```
SELECT *
  FROM ORDER
  WHERE DUE_DATE = CURRENT_DATE AND
        ROWNUM <= 10
  ORDER BY DUE_DATE ASC
```

However, even I have a bunch of order has due date as today, the query actually return 0 rows.

How come? Thanks in advance.

Sorry I forget to mention the DUE_DATE is of type `Date`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either truncate your dates, as in

```
SELECT *
  FROM ORDER
  WHERE TRUNC(DUE_DATE) = TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) AND
        ROWNUM <= 10
  ORDER BY DUE_DATE ASC
```

or use a ranged comparison, as in

```
SELECT *
  FROM ORDER
  WHERE DUE_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)
                     AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AND
        ROWNUM <= 10
  ORDER BY DUE_DATE ASC
```

The latter example may perform better because an index can be used (assuming you have an index on DUE_DATE).  Of course, you could also add a function-based index on TRUNC(DUE_DATE) in which case either would likely perform equally well.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

CURRENT_DATE contains the month, the day and the year. Your due date probably contains hour, minute, second too. If so, you should truncate your dates when you are doing the comparison.

Comment: If you execute `SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL` you'll note that CURRENT_DATE also includes hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: Yes, basicly you need to compare dates in the very same data representation.